# asp.net - get the text of the selected item in a radiobutton group

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, radio-button, groupname

I've found this code, but I was wondering whether there's a more streamlined way to do it.

So for example, rather than having all the if statements can you have one line that says Label1.text = "You selected " & RadioGroup1.Text

```
  Sub SubmitBtn_Click(Sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
     If Radio1.Checked Then
        Label1.Text = "You selected " & Radio1.Text
     ElseIf Radio2.Checked Then
        Label1.Text = "You selected " & Radio2.Text
     ElseIf Radio3.Checked Then
        Label1.Text = "You selected " & Radio3.Text
     End If
  End Sub
```

and

```
   <asp:RadioButton id=Radio1 Text="Typical" Checked="True" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />

   <asp:RadioButton id=Radio2 Text="Compact" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server"/>

   <asp:RadioButton id=Radio3 Text="Full" GroupName="RadioGroup1" runat="server" />

   <asp:Button text="Submit" OnClick="SubmitBtn_Click" runat=server/>

   <asp:Label id=Label1 Font-Bold="true"  runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `<asp:radiobuttonlist>` have it's id as `radio1`. Then have seperate `<asp:listitem>` in there. Set each list item with a different `value`, ie, Typical, Contact, Full. Then all you would need in `SubmitBtn_Click` would be `radio1.SelectedItem.Value`

Answer (score 1):

The RadioButtonList will help reduce code:

```
<p>
    <strong>Output:</strong>
    <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lOut" />
</p>
<asp:RadioButtonList runat="server" ID="rblist1" AutoPostBack="true"     onselectedindexchanged="rblist1_SelectedIndexChanged"  >
    <asp:ListItem Value="1">One</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="2">Two</asp:ListItem>
    <asp:ListItem Value="3">Three</asp:ListItem>
</asp:RadioButtonList>


protected void rblist1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.lOut.Text = string.Format("RadioButton: selected: {0}={1} ", rblist1.SelectedItem.Text, rblist1.SelectedValue);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
string valueName = Radio3.Text;
```